# React Router v4 dynamic route not able to refresh

Tags: react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I have been searching for a solution on this and have not had any luck. I have a app using the **BrowserRouter** and has **dynamic routes** as the user goes deeper into the flow. I have some server side rendering for static routes that work for rendering after refresh, but my dynamic routes get a 404 upon refresh.

I'm think that getting this to work (refreshing dynamic routes) is probably not possible, but I'm hoping that my application can at least forward the user to the land page or route upon refresh of a dynamic route. That would be preferable to a 404 error page on refresh. Just not sure how to achieve that.

Hope that makes sense for the most part. Thanks is advance for any help.